# Fake User for all animations on selected object

Tags: scripting

First of all, I'm not too familiar with python.

What I'd like to happen, is that for the selected object/objects, it should get their animations and set their *use_fake_user = True* (due to bone retargeting, but every save they are gone, having to reimport the animations).

So far, all I've got is:

```
# Selected objects in viewport into array objects
selName = []
    for i in bpy.context.selected_objects:
        selName.append(i.name)
```

Due to animations and materials having different names, calling them through the object names won't fly (tried bpy.data.actions).

How do I solve this issue? Or is there a more effective way?

Edit: It seems there's no real "connection" between animation data and objects. So it's either manual or all of them. I'd wager something along the lines of:

```
from itertools import chain

for i in chain(bpy.data.actions):
    i.use_fake_user = true
```